Back transform from gamma
NADA::cenros has a function to transform prior to performing a ROS fit (e.g., "gamma"). It also has a function for reversing the transformation afterwards, I don't know of a named transformation to call on to reverse a gamma transformation. I tried "cube" and "^3" and ^3, but none of them worked.
